# On which element should i apply transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a project in which i needed to show heading for a topic and when the mouse goes over it, it changes to information of that heading. I have managed to make it work however i don't want it to change instantly, i want to apply transition on it so it makes it more pleasing. The problem is i don't know which element to put it on. I tried to put it on all three but it didn't work. I would appreciate if someone helped me with it. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="sop-container">
           <div class="sop-body"  onmouseover="showSop()" onmouseout="hideSop()">
               <h1 id="sop-head">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
               <p class="sop-p" id="sop-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, tempore laudantium maiores eligendi tempora ab repellat nam possimus sit molestiae cumque officiis corporis optio officia commodi consequatur aperiam quaerat odit.</p>
           </div>
           <div class="sop-img">   
                <img src="masks.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
       </div>
```

CSS

```
.sop-body{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #EAC435;
    transition: 3s ease;
    

}

.sop-body h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:125px;
    transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}




.sop-body p{
    display: none;
    margin:5%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: large;
    margin-top: 80px ;
    transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}



.sop-img{
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  
}
```

Javascript (just in case)

```
var sopBody = document.getElementById("sop-p");
var sopHead = document.getElementById("sop-head")

function showSop(){
    sopBody.style.display = "block"
    sopHead.style.display = "none"

}

function hideSop(){
    sopBody.style.display = "none"
    sopHead.style.display = "block"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transition` doesn't work on the `display` property. Just think for a moment about how could you render a partial display element. You can't.

Alternatively, you can use `opacity` here

```js
var sopBody = document.getElementById("sop-p");
var sopHead = document.getElementById("sop-head")

function showSop() {
  sopBody.style.opacity = "1"
  sopHead.style.opacity = "0"
}

function hideSop() {
  sopBody.style.opacity = "0"
  sopHead.style.opacity = "1"
}
```

```css
.sop-body {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #EAC435;
}

.sop-body h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 125px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.sop-body p {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 5%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: large;
  margin-top: 80px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.sop-img {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sop-container">
  <div class="sop-body" onmouseover="showSop()" onmouseout="hideSop()">
    <h1 id="sop-head">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p class="sop-p" id="sop-p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, tempore laudantium maiores eligendi tempora ab repellat nam possimus sit molestiae cumque officiis corporis optio officia commodi consequatur aperiam quaerat odit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sop-img">
    <img src="masks.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it does give the effect but wouldn't it make the p tag pushed down a little bit

Comment: You can add effect as per you need.

Comment: but it is not working in my code for some reason it makes the heading go away but doesn't show the p tag